# Advice for a user-friendly relationship dropdown

Tags: relationships, control-panel

i have a channel screenings with a relationship with movie.
The screening channel has date, place and movie relationship with dropdown.

the dropdown has now about 1000+ movies in it. Is there eg a choosen plugin on EE to replace the dropdown? (this one seems to be in beta http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/chosen-selects )

Best
Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pixel & Tonic's [Playa](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa), which is a many to many relationship field, does have one seriously awesome benefit for you in this regard - filtering. It allows you to filter by category and search by keyword - so it may be that feature alone that makes it worth your while for this purpose.

Comment: +1 for Playa. Playa also has a *single select* mode with filtering.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a true relationship field, then as Jean said, go with Playa's single select mode.

If this is just a plain old *select* field then take a look at the [**Chosen Selects**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/chosen-selects) fieldtype by John D. Wells. It's based on the Chosen jQuery plugin ([demo here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)), which makes really long select menus easier to work with by adding filter as you type.